# com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:

Tags: spring-mvc, ibatis, dynamic-sql

I am gettng this exception for this code

```
 List<String> addlCarrierClause=new ArrayList<String>();

<select id="GET_SEARCH_RESULTS" parameterClass="Map" resultClass="HashMap">

<isNotEmpty  prepend=" AND " property="addlClauseGtwyTemp">
    l.imp_gtwy_i in
        <iterate property="addlClauseGtwyTemp" open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
            #addlClauseGtwyTemp[]#
        </iterate>
</isNotEmpty>
```

**com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException**:

```
The error occurred while preparing the mapped statement for execution.  
--- Check the GET_SEARCH_RESULTS.  
--- Check the parameter map.  
--- Cause: com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapException: ParameterObject or property was not a Collection, Array or Iterator.
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
```

Am I using the `iterate tag` correctly?
What else do i need to check to implement this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use iBatis `<iterate>` tag only when you want to cycle through a list of items.
Your iterate tag usage is correct and your property **addlClauseGtwyTemp** exists otherwise you'll be getting a `NullPointerException` which you aren't getting. So your problem simply is that your **addlClauseGtwyTemp** isn't a list or an iterable collection (implementing an iterable interface) but a flat value.

I was able to simulate your issue locally and i got the same stack trace in my logs

```
2013-09-02 17:04:59,724 ERROR UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred processing wlm.search
com.xyz.event.InvalidEventStateException: wlm.searchCO:
--- The error occurred in workListManagementSearchService.xml.
--- The error occurred while preparing the mapped statement for execution.
--- Check the getWLMSearchCustomers.
--- Check the parameter map.
--- Cause: com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapException: ParameterObject or property was not a Collection, Array or Iterator.
        at com.xyz.event.Query.execute(Query.java:67)
        at com.xyz.event.AbstractParentExecutable.executeChildren(AbstractParentExecutable.java:35)
        at com.xyz.event.Event.execute(Event.java:32)
        at com.xyz.event.impl.d$a.processEvent(EventContextFactory.java:56)
```

**SOLUTION**

Ensure that your property **addlClauseGtwyTemp** is a list or a collection and not a flat value.

**LIST**

```
addlClauseGtwyTemp = [Asia,America,Austalia,Africa,SouthAmerica,Europe]
```

**NON LIST**

```
addlClauseGtwyTemp = Asia
```

**EXTRA TIPS**

In your case you are guarding and checking this property **addlClauseGtwyTemp** is not null and not empty `("" or size() < 1)` using `<isNotEmpty>` tag.

Well, that's fine and i'll also commend that using `<isNotEmpty>` is more efficient than using `<isNotNull>` since `<isNotNull>` only checks if the property is not null but does not check if the property **addlClauseGtwyTemp** is not empty that is, the size of the property **addlClauseGtwyTemp** is less than 1 `size() < 1`. If it is null or if the size is less than 1 then the code nested in that tag will not run.  But what happens if that property fails to met your `<isNotEmpty>` condition? Using your code that you have pasted in your question the query will throw an error. This means that you have to have a preceding code that does the reverse of this to handle situations where the condition fails to be satisfied.

```
<select id="GET_SEARCH_RESULTS" parameterClass="Map" resultClass="HashMap">

    <isNotEmpty  prepend=" AND " property="addlClauseGtwyTemp">
        l.imp_gtwy_i in
        <iterate property="addlClauseGtwyTemp" open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
        #addlClauseGtwyTemp[]#
        </iterate>
    </isNotEmpty>

    <isEmpty  prepend=" AND " property="addlClauseGtwyTemp">
       1=2
    </isEmpty>

    <isNull property="addlClauseGtwyTemp">
          select 1 from dual (Oracle syntax)
          select 1 (Postgres/MySQL)
    </isNull>

</select>
```

I added a fragment to check the reverse of isNotEmpty using `<isEmpty>` tag and i also checked if **addlClauseGtwyTemp** is null using `<isNull>`. If it is null then the query does nothing rather than throw an error.